# Swift: FCM notification not received

Tags: php, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-notifications

I use FCM for notification.

In firebase console i can send notification, but by PHP code not received and cant custom it

PHP code :

```
$data['TITLE'] = $title;
$data['TEXT'] = $text;

$fcmFields = array('to'=>$to,
                   'data'=>$data,
                   'priority'=>'high',
                   'time_to_live'=>$time);

$headers = array('Authorization: key='.API_ACCESS_KEY,'Content-Type: application/json');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($fcmFields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
```

Note: by this php code i can send notification android devices

Swift Code :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")
    }
}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler([])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
}
```

1- I can send notification by google console and received but not prints anything in my app log

2- I can send notification to android devices by php codes but i cant send for ios devices

3- `didReceiveRemoteNotification` completely not work

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add 'notification' in PHP code and fixed

```
$fcmFields = array('to'=>$to,
                   'data'=>$data,
                   'notification'=>array('title'=>'x','body'=>'y'),
                   'priority'=>'high',
                   'time_to_live'=>$time);
```